# Soap is not working in PHP

Tags: php, api, soap

I am using [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) but I am not able to get the result. I get this error:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the
>   exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the
>   server trace logs.

```
<?php
  $silverpop = new SoapClient($my_url, array('trace' => 1));
  /*$client =   new stdClass();
  $client->LoginID  =   'mylogin-id';
  $client->LicenceKey   =   'mylicense-key';*/

  $clientobj = (object) array("LoginID" => "mylogin-id", "LicenceKey" => "mylicense-key");

  try {
    //$var  =    $silverpop->__soapCall("GetServicesforPincode",array('P_Pincode'=>'110014','P_ClientObject'=>$clientobj));
    //$var  =   $silverpop->GetServicesforPincode('110014',$clientobj);
    $var = $silverpop -> __soapCall("GetServicesforPincode", array('110014', $clientobj));
  } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo $exception -> getMessage();
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($var);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which type of response u r expecting

Comment: any type. Till now I was looking for XML

Comment: cool . I am posting one solution down in this post. Give a try and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Either you have send your data not according to the specifications or your SoapServer is not working. I think the first one as Soap isn't always as clear as it should. As it looks like the error message is actually generated by the SoapServer, I recommend checking the schema for allowed parameters/calls and their format. If that's all correct, check if you are missing headers etc.

If all of the above is correct, fix your SoapServer. If you haven't gotten access to it, poke the owner.

Comment: that's what I am thinking too that data is not according to specifications but I tried all the possible ways but not getting any other response except that error.How to check whether soap is fine or not

Answer (score 0):

try{
        $client = new SoapClient($my_url,array('trace' => 1));
        $object = new stdClass();
        $object->LoginID  =   'mylogin-id';
        $object->LicenceKey   =   'mylicense-key';

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($client->GetServicesforPincode($object));
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    print_r($json);
}

catch (SoapFault $exception) { echo $exception; }
```

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given                null

Comment: PinCode - value
PincodeDescription- value
AreaCode- value
ServiceCenterCode- value
DomesticPriorityInbound- value
DomesticPriorityOutbound- value
ApexInbound- value
ApexOutbound- value
GroundInbound- value
GroundOutbound- value
eTailCODAirInbound- value
eTailCODAirOutbound- value
eTailCODGroundInbound- value
eTailCODGroundOutbound- value
eTailPrePaidAirInbound- value
eTailPrePaidAirOutound- value
eTailPrePaidGroundInbound- value
eTailPrePaidGroundOutbound- value
DomesticPriorityTDD- value
ApexTDD- value
ErrorMessage- value
IsError- value